# C# WebBrowser for PDF preview becomes for Html

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, webbrowser-control

I have a Windows Form Application, implemented by others, that lists a collection of files; among these files there are PDF also. I would like to provide a preview of each .pdf instance.
As my application must be compiled x64 I can not use the Adobe-Libraries, because they don't support 64-bit...so I've turned into `WebBrowser.Navigate("pdfpath")` method. The WebBrowser instance is inside a `User Control`.

First of all I I've tested this solution in a separated stupid Windows Form application, and it works perfectly. Here the WebBrowser object content resulting from the VS Immediate Window:
[image]

Then I've used the same technique inside the real project... and here is my problem: the WebBrowser instance's content in this case is complitely different:
[image]

And in this case the pdf preview is not available (the `browser.Navigate( "pdfpath" )` call does not anything!).

Why these objects are different although I don't change anything explicitly?
Any hint about what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: Screenshots of source code looks very strange to me.

Comment: It's not source code, it is the Immediate Window result... here is the content of both WebBrowser instances!